# how to find a specific value missing when a column has multiple values?

Tags: sql, where-clause

i have a table with the column billID. Each BillID will have multiple tariffs. i wants to find out the bills which are missing specific tariff. For example one BillID have tariffs A,B,C,D. i want to find out the BillIDs which dont have the Tariff D. i have tried the below query using the where condition as Tariff<>D but its showing the same bill which has the tariffs A,B,C. your help in this appreciated.

```
Select b.BillID
from bill b
inner join tariff t on t.billid = b.billid
where t.tariff not in ('d')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your query like following using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT b.BillID
FROM bill b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tariff t
        WHERE t.billid = b.billid
            AND t.tariff = 'd'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT b.BillID
  FROM bill b
 GROUP BY b.BillID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN b.BillID = 'd' THEN 1 END) = 0
```